# Changing color of Paint object dynamically in Android

Tags: android

I have a Options `Activity`, where I select the color using a `RadioButton`. By default, the `White` color is set `android:checked="true"`. Now when I reach to my `Canvas`,I need to change the `Paint` color dynamically depending on which `RadioButton` was selected.
Here's the code that I have tried:

```
            String radioButtonSelected = "";
            switch (checkedRadioButton) {
              case R.id.CheckRed : radioButtonSelected = "Red";
                                              break;
              case R.id.CheckBlue : radioButtonSelected = "Blue";
                                          break;
              case R.id.CheckWhite : radioButtonSelected = "White";
                                          break;
            }
            Intent i = new Intent(HandwritingRecognitionOptionTab.this,HandwritingRecognitionCanvas.class);
            i.putExtra("setColor",radioButtonSelected);
            //startActivity(i); // because I don't want to start the activity immediately after this
```

In the class for `Canvas`:

```
        Bundle getValue = getIntent().getExtras();
        drawColor = getValue.getString("setColor");
        if(drawColor.equals("White"))
            intColor = 1;
        if(drawColor.equals("Red"))
            intColor = 2;
        if(drawColor.equals("Blue"))
            intColor = 3;


        mPaint = new Paint();
        mPaint.setDither(true);
        mPaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        if(intColor == 1)
            mPaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        if(intColor == 2)
            mPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
        if(intColor == 3)
            mPaint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
```

But I get a `NullPointerException` whenever the `Activity` for `Canvas` is started. It is important to note that by default White should be the color. Also, this doesn't store it persistently right? Should I look into [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) for this ?

Comment: If that is not the point from where you are starting the second activity can you put the relevent code from whereever you are starting the second activity.

Comment: I don't start the other activity from this activity. I'm getting a feeling that I'm totally wrong in this approach, ie, choosing putExtra().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading through your comments it looks like that you are not starting the other activity using the given Intent and hence the NullPointerException as the Bundle wont be containg the same string in the next activity.

You can opt out for the following options:

```
1> Shared Prefrences (As highlighted by you)
2> Some DB entry.
3> Some file storage
4> Singleton pattern
```

but for me the best one would have been a shared prefrence. You might also want to have a look at this [link](http://developer.android.com/resources/faq/framework.html) for a detail